# While running testcases using testng.xml getting error depends on nonexistent group

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Running classes with attribute dependsOnGroupsis working fine while running individual as TestNG , But while running them using testng.xml file getting Below error

I'm not able to figure out why getting that error , May be some dependency need to add in testing.xml file that I may be missing. Anyone's help will be more appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
 [TestNG] Running:
      C:\Workspace\ZionsWorkspace\Zions_Bancs_Automation\testng.xml

org.testng.TestNGException: 
DependencyMap::Method "LoanApprovalTest.testLoanApprova(java.util.Hashtable)[pri:0, instance:com.zions.release1.Sanity.LoanTestCases.LoanApprovalTest@3884b2]" depends on nonexistent group "CreateLoanAccountTest.testCreateLoanAccount"
    at org.testng.DependencyMap.getMethodsThatBelongTo(DependencyMap.java:46)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.createDynamicGraph(TestRunner.java:1074)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:734)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Class 1 :

```
        public class CreateLoanAccountTest extends AbstractBaseTestCase{

            private CreateLoanAccountProcess createLoanAccountProcess =  null;

            @Test(dataProvider="createLoanAccountTest" , dataProviderClass = DataProviderForSanitTest.class , groups={"CreateLoanAccountTest.testCreateLoanAccount"})
            public void testCreateLoanAccount(Hashtable<String, String> TestDataTable){


            }

        }
```

Class 2 :

```
        public class LoanApprovalTest extends AbstractBaseTestCase {

                  @Test(dataProvider="loanApprovalTest" , dataProviderClass = DataProviderForSanitTest.class , dependsOnGroups={"CreateLoanAccountTest.testCreateLoanAccount"}) 
                   public void testLoanApprova(Hashtable<String, String> TestDataTable){

                   }

        }
```

Testng.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
        <!-- parallel="methods" To Execute the classess Parallel -->
        <suite name="Suite"  >
          <test name="Test">

        <class name="com.zions.release1.Sanity.LoanTestCases.LoanApprovalTest"/>
               <class name="com.zions.release1.Sanity.LoanTestCases.AmendLoanAccountTest"/>
            </classes>
          </test> <!-- Test -->
        </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0):

While I included the depends on class in testing.xml file, it started working , But the order in which they are running is not what's expected.

Loan Approval depends on Loan Creation , Loan amendment is independent testcase

Execution order is : 
Creating loan account ,
Loan amendment ,
log approval

it was expected to be
Loan Creation ,
Loan Approval ,
Loan Amendment

I'm not able to understand why it's happening. Can any one explain the execution order while keeping the classes in testing File with those class having dependsongroups attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<!-- parallel="methods" To Execute the classess Parallel -->
<suite name="Suite"  >
  <test name="Test">


    <classes>


  <class name="com.zions.release1.Sanity.LoanTestCases.CreateLoanAccountTest"/>
       <class name="com.zions.release1.Sanity.LoanTestCases.LoanApprovalTest"/>
       <class name="com.zions.release1.Sanity.LoanTestCases.AmendLoanAccountTest" />
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: The order is another question. In any case, you should simplify your sample because it is really difficult to follow you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are only worried about the execution order, you will have to make 2 changes :
1. In your testng.xml file, you will have to add :

```
test name="Test" **preserve-order="true"**
```

This will ensure the execution order of the test class mentioned in the testng.xml file. Follow this link for more details http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/preserve-order-in-testng

2. In case you want to ensure the priority order within a class, you will have to do something like :

> @Test(priority=1)
>           public void Test1() {}
>
> @Test(priority=2)
>           public void Test2() {}
>
> @Test(priority=3)
>           public void Test3() {}

`priority` encourages execution order but does not guarantee the previous priority level has completed. test3 could start before test2 completes. If a guarantee is needed, then declare a dependency.

Unlike the solutions which declare dependencies, tests which use priority will execute even if one test fails. This problem with dependencies can be worked around with @Test(...alwaysRun = true...) according to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: Hi Anshul , i tried with preserve-order=true in the testng file , But it's behaving the same way , the class having groups attribute is executing in the last even it's placed between create account and amendment of loan account. between thanks for your reply , that's quire informative.  i did the solution of this problem by keeping the separate class as a method in same class and use dependsonmethod, then order is working as expected.

Comment: Other issue now i have is running my testcases with multiple data set , like i have one class for account creation but two data set, so in extent report showing the calss is executed twice with same name , now to change the name for each execution i want to pass Testcase name from excel and want to pass that value in by before  method. where i'm initializing my extent report. But now finding any way to pass that testcase name as variable from method to before method :( i thought all possible way , but couldn't make it , Please let me know if you know the solution